# QT and window.open

Tags: c++, qt, window.open, qtwebkit, qwebpage

I am developing a browser, it will have support for tabs.

But I have a difficulty, `QWebPage::createWindow` does not differentiate `window.open` to `<a href="" targert="">`.

eg.:

```
<script>
    var params = "menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no";
    window.open("http://www.cnn.com/", "_blank", params);
</script>
```

and

```
<a href="http://www.cnn.com/" target="_blank">
```

are considered the same by `QWebPage::createWindow`

How to differentiate both?

> When `window.open` I will create a window and when anchors will add a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `QWebPage`, whenever we open a "popup" window using `window.open(...)` or `window.showModal(...)` she always sends these signals:

```
toolBarVisibilityChangeRequested(bool))
menuBarVisibilityChangeRequested(bool))
statusBarVisibilityChangeRequested(bool))
```

Whether or not you've added parameters to your "Popup".
So using these signs I could differentiate when it is "popup" and when it's a normal "link".